# Failed updating from 8.8.8 to 8.9.2

Tags: 8, composer

I want to update my Drupal website from 8.8.8 to 8.9.2.

I have separately tried each of the below:

1. Run `composer update`
2. Removing both `Vendor` directory and `composer.lock` file then run `composer install`
3. Removing both `Vendor` directory and `composer.lock` file then run `composer update`
4. Manually changing all lines in `composer.json` file (`"drupal/core-composer-scaffold"` and `"drupal/core-project-message"` and `"drupal/core-recommended"`) from `^8.8` to `^8.9` then run `composer install`

None of the above worked for me and the site still until now running on "Drupal 8.8.8"

I have my own backup in case something wrong happened :)

For example when I removing both `Vendor` directory and `composer.lock` file then ran `composer update` command, I received the below:

```
user@user.com [~/public_html/dev.example.com]# composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 28 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating drupal/core-composer-scaffold (8.8.5 => 8.9.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating drupal/core-project-message (8.8.5 => 8.9.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating composer/installers (v1.7.0 => v1.9.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.18.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.16.0 => v1.18.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/var-dumper (v4.4.8 => v4.4.11): Loading from cache
  - Updating webmozart/assert (1.8.0 => 1.9.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating drupal/better_exposed_filters (4.0.0-beta1 => 4.0.0-beta2): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating drupal/conditional_fields (1.0.0-alpha8 => 1.0.0-alpha9): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating drupal/flag (4.0.0-beta1 => 4.0.0-beta2): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating drupal/fontawesome (2.16.0 => 2.17.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating drupal/simplify (1.1.0 => 1.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating drupal/sms_simplegateway (1.1.0 => 1.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating drupal/webform (6.0.0-alpha8 => 6.0.0-alpha12):  Checking out 6.0.0-alpha12
  - Updating symfony/finder (v4.4.8 => v4.4.11): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating nikic/php-parser (v4.4.0 => v4.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating consolidation/site-alias (3.0.0 => 3.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/filesystem (v4.4.8 => v4.4.11): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating chi-teck/drupal-code-generator (1.32.0 => 1.32.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating drush/drush (10.2.2 => 10.3.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating algolia/places (1.17.1 => 1.18.2): Loading from cache
  - Updating codemirror/codemirror (5.51.0 => 5.53.2): Loading from cache
  - Updating jquery/image-picker (0.3.0 => 0.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating jquery/select2 (4.0.12 => 4.0.13): Loading from cache
  - Updating jquery/textcounter (0.8.0 => 0.9.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating jquery/timepicker (1.13.0 => 1.13.10): Loading from cache
  - Updating progress-tracker/progress-tracker (1.4.0 => 2.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Updating giggsey/locale (1.8 => 1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php (8.12.3 => 8.12.4): Loading from cache
Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
Package zendframework/zend-diactoros is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-diactoros instead.
Package zendframework/zend-escaper is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-escaper instead.
Package zendframework/zend-feed is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-feed instead.
Package zendframework/zend-stdlib is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-stdlib instead.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Scaffolding files for drupal/core:
  - Copy [project-root]/.editorconfig from assets/scaffold/files/editorconfig
  - Copy [project-root]/.gitattributes from assets/scaffold/files/gitattributes
  - Copy [web-root]/.csslintrc from assets/scaffold/files/csslintrc
  - Copy [web-root]/.eslintignore from assets/scaffold/files/eslintignore
  - Copy [web-root]/.eslintrc.json from assets/scaffold/files/eslintrc.json
  - Copy [web-root]/.ht.router.php from assets/scaffold/files/ht.router.php
  - Copy [web-root]/.htaccess from assets/scaffold/files/htaccess
  - Copy [web-root]/example.gitignore from assets/scaffold/files/example.gitignore
  - Copy [web-root]/index.php from assets/scaffold/files/index.php
  - Copy [web-root]/INSTALL.txt from assets/scaffold/files/drupal.INSTALL.txt
  - Copy [web-root]/README.txt from assets/scaffold/files/drupal.README.txt
  - Copy [web-root]/robots.txt from assets/scaffold/files/robots.txt
  - Copy [web-root]/update.php from assets/scaffold/files/update.php
  - Copy [web-root]/web.config from assets/scaffold/files/web.config
  - Copy [web-root]/sites/README.txt from assets/scaffold/files/sites.README.txt
  - Copy [web-root]/sites/development.services.yml from assets/scaffold/files/development.services.yml
  - Copy [web-root]/sites/example.settings.local.php from assets/scaffold/files/example.settings.local.php
  - Copy [web-root]/sites/example.sites.php from assets/scaffold/files/example.sites.php
  - Copy [web-root]/sites/default/default.services.yml from assets/scaffold/files/default.services.yml
  - Copy [web-root]/sites/default/default.settings.php from assets/scaffold/files/default.settings.php
  - Copy [web-root]/modules/README.txt from assets/scaffold/files/modules.README.txt
  - Copy [web-root]/profiles/README.txt from assets/scaffold/files/profiles.README.txt
  - Copy [web-root]/themes/README.txt from assets/scaffold/files/themes.README.txt
```

Yet the site is running on 8.8.8 Core and the `/admin/reports/updates/update` section of my site still asking me to update `core` from `8.8.8` to `8.9.2`

As shown above, there is no errors at all and the update seems to be running smoothly.

Any idea what I am missing here ?

**UPDATE #1:**

I have tried `composer update --with-dependencies` and got the below output:

```
  - Updating drupal/core-composer-scaffold (8.8.5 => 8.9.2): Loading from cache
  - Updating drupal/core-project-message (8.8.5 => 8.9.2): Loading from cache
  - Updating composer/installers (v1.7.0 => v1.9.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.18.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.16.0 => v1.18.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/var-dumper (v4.4.8 => v4.4.11): Loading from cache
  - Updating webmozart/assert (1.8.0 => 1.9.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating drupal/better_exposed_filters (4.0.0-beta1 => 4.0.0-beta2): Loading from cache
  - Updating drupal/conditional_fields (1.0.0-alpha8 => 1.0.0-alpha9): Loading from cache
  - Updating drupal/flag (4.0.0-beta1 => 4.0.0-beta2): Loading from cache
  - Updating drupal/fontawesome (2.16.0 => 2.17.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating drupal/simplify (1.1.0 => 1.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating drupal/sms_simplegateway (1.1.0 => 1.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating drupal/webform (6.0.0-alpha8 => 6.0.0-alpha12):  Checking out 6.0.0-alpha12
  - Updating symfony/finder (v4.4.8 => v4.4.11): Loading from cache
  - Updating nikic/php-parser (v4.4.0 => v4.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating consolidation/site-alias (3.0.0 => 3.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating symfony/filesystem (v4.4.8 => v4.4.11): Loading from cache
  - Updating chi-teck/drupal-code-generator (1.32.0 => 1.32.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating drush/drush (10.2.2 => 10.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating algolia/places (1.17.1 => 1.18.2): Loading from cache
  - Updating codemirror/codemirror (5.51.0 => 5.53.2): Loading from cache
  - Updating jquery/image-picker (0.3.0 => 0.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Updating jquery/select2 (4.0.12 => 4.0.13): Loading from cache
  - Updating jquery/textcounter (0.8.0 => 0.9.0): Loading from cache
  - Updating jquery/timepicker (1.13.0 => 1.13.10): Loading from cache
  - Updating progress-tracker/progress-tracker (1.4.0 => 2.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Updating giggsey/locale (1.8 => 1.9): Loading from cache
  - Updating giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php (8.12.3 => 8.12.4): Loading from cache
```

then I ran `drush updb` and `drush cr` and yet the site still running on Core 8.8.8 !?!?!

Also, I have tried to run `composer prohibits drupal/core` to see what is preventing the site update and I got the below results:

```
user@example.com [~/public_html/dev.example.com]# composer prohibits drupal/core
drupal/addtoany                    1.14.0        requires  drupal/core (^8 || ^9)
drupal/admin_toolbar               2.3.0         requires  drupal/core (^8.8.0 || ^9.0)
drupal/better_exposed_filters      4.0.0-beta1   requires  drupal/core (^8 || ^9)
drupal/blazy                       2.1.0         requires  drupal/core (^8.8 || ^9)
drupal/business_rules              1.0.0-beta10  requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/captcha                     1.1.0         requires  drupal/core (^8.8 || ^9)
drupal/change_pwd_page             1.0.0         requires  drupal/core (^8 || ^9)
drupal/colorbox                    1.6.0         requires  drupal/core (^8.8 || ^9)
drupal/conditional_fields          1.0.0-alpha8  requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/core-recommended            8.8.8         requires  drupal/core (8.8.8)
drupal/ctools                      3.4.0         requires  drupal/core (^8.7.7 || ^9)
drupal/dbug                        1.0.0         requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/dynamic_entity_reference    1.10.0        requires  drupal/core (^8.7.7 || ^9)
drupal/entity_reference_revisions  1.8.0         requires  drupal/core (^8.7.7 || ^9)
drupal/eva                         2.1.0         requires  drupal/core (^8 || ^9)
drupal/field_group                 3.1.0         requires  drupal/core (^8.8 || ^9)
drupal/field_permissions           1.0.0         requires  drupal/core (^8 || ^9)
drupal/field_timer                 1.x-dev       requires  drupal/core (^8 || ^9)
drupal/firebase                    2.0.0         requires  drupal/core (^8.3.0)
drupal/flag                        4.0.0-beta1   requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/fontawesome                 2.16.0        requires  drupal/core (^8 || ^9)
drupal/google_analytics            3.1.0         requires  drupal/core (^8.8.6|^9.0)
drupal/jquery_ui                   1.4.0         requires  drupal/core (^8 || ^9)
drupal/jquery_ui_accordion         1.1.0         requires  drupal/core (^8 || ^9)
drupal/jquery_ui_checkboxradio     1.2.0         requires  drupal/core (^8 || ^9)
drupal/jquery_ui_datepicker        1.0.0         requires  drupal/core (^8 || ^9)
drupal/jquery_ui_tabs              1.1.0         requires  drupal/core (^8 || ^9)
drupal/jquery_ui_tooltip           1.1.0         requires  drupal/core (^8 || ^9)
drupal/module_filter               3.1.0         requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/pathauto                    1.8.0         requires  drupal/core (^8.8 || ^9)
drupal/persistent_login            1.3.0         requires  drupal/core (^8.3 || ^9.0)
drupal/reroute_email               1.2.0         requires  drupal/core (^8 || ^9)
drupal/simple_fb_connect           3.1.0         requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/simplify                    1.1.0         requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/sitewide_alert              1.3.0         requires  drupal/core (^8 || ^9)
drupal/slick                       2.2.0         requires  drupal/core (^8.8 || ^9)
drupal/slick_views                 2.3.0         requires  drupal/core (^8 || ^9)
drupal/sms                         1.3.0         requires  drupal/core (>=8.6 <8.9)
drupal/sms_simplegateway           1.1.0         requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/smsframework                1.3.0         requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/subpathauto                 1.1.0         requires  drupal/core (^8.8 || ^9)
drupal/telephone_validation        2.3.0         requires  drupal/core (^8 || ^9)
drupal/token                       1.7.0         requires  drupal/core (^8.7.7 || ^9)
drupal/token_filter                1.2.0         requires  drupal/core (^8 || ^9)
drupal/ultimate_cron               2.0.0-alpha4  requires  drupal/core (~8.0)
drupal/video                       1.4.0         requires  drupal/core (*)
drupal/views_infinite_scroll       1.7.0         requires  drupal/core (^8.8 || ^9)
drupal/webform                     6.0.0-alpha8  requires  drupal/core (^8.8 || ^9)
```

Thank you,

Comment: What's the error that you're getting? Try running composer with verbose (add `-v` to the command) and then add the error message to your question.

Comment: @PatrickKenny there is no errors at all, please check the update of the question.

Comment: Seems like your database is out of date, as the composer output is clear enough that it's installed 8.9.2. Try running database updates and clearing cache

Comment: @Clive I did `drush updb` and `drush cr` many times and yet same problem, even in `/admin/reports/status` the core listed is `8.8.8`

Comment: Look at the files on disk to verify, each core module should have a version in its info file. Also make sure the right code is connected to the right database etc

Comment: @Clive All core modules have `Core: 8.x` and I double checked the Database connection in my `settings.php` file and it is correct.

Comment: What happens if you try to update only core, e.g. `composer update drupal/core-recommended`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your prohibits output, `drupal/sms` is blocking the update:

> requires  drupal/core (>=8.6 <8.9)

You can try switching to [smsframework](https://www.drupal.org/project/smsframework).

Answer (score 0):

You should run:

```
composer update --with-dependencies
```

If that doesn't work, run:

```
composer prohibits drupal/core
```

That should tell you what is holding back the update of drupal/core.

Comment: I ran `composer prohibits drupal/core` and updated my question with the output, can you please check it out to see if there is something important ?

Comment: @VanessaAbiRashed, this looks like the key line: `drupal/core-recommended            8.8.8         requires  drupal/core (8.8.8)`. It's pinned at 8.8.8 specifically. Try running `composer update drupal/core drupal/core-recommended --with-dependencies`